Sci-fi novel exploring time dilation as a man escapes to a castle tower and witnesses the universe's death
I'm looking to identify this sci-fi novel about a man who escapes to a castle tower chased by a mysterious being.
The protagonist eventually lifts into space and loses all sense of time as he watches galaxies merge and the universe die.
Floating into space, he eventually lives to the length of the universe.
Read in approximately 1984, so it may have been from the '60s?

It sounds a little like Star Maker by Olaf Stapledon but there is no escape or castle or chase.  Can you have a look at the plot synopsis to rule that out?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Maker

Yes it's not that. I liked because the protagonist waits in the tower while the being below watches until the castle resolves..

Vague memories of "In The World's Dust" in Asimov's The Last Man on Earth anthology? Or maybe another story from that anthology.

Why do you keep rolling back edits to your question's title?

SO long shot, but this may be a vision that Roland has in "The Dark Tower: The Gunslinger" by Stephen King. Originally published in (I think) 1982

Another long shot with some similarities is William Hope Hodgson's THE HOUSE ON THE BORDERLAND, which is summarized here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_House_on_the_Borderland

Thanks John sounds interesting but not that thanks for efforts.

Of course it's not that, but it feels so similar on some points to Doctor's who Heaven Sent, i'm wonder if this novel was the inspiration for the episode.
